For what kind of systems ML-MCTDH won't work with a vibronic coupling Hamiltonian?
In solving the time-dependent Schrödinger equation (TDSE), the multiconfiguration time-dependent Hartree (MCTDH) method is an extremely versatile and powerful tool to simulate ultrafast processes and for which quantum effects need to be accounted for in describing the nuclear degrees of freedom. Due to its exponential scaling, when dealing with large dimensionality systems, it is customary to use the multilayer extension (ML-MCTDH), in which the wavefunction is formulated as a hierarchical expansion, thus reducing the algorithmic scaling to polynomial.
For molecular processes where non-adiabatic effects are prominent, the Hamiltonian, $H$, is most typically represented in its vibronic coupling form, i.e.:
$$
H = \sum_{ij}\left(T_{ii}\delta_{ij}+V_{ij}(\{\mathbf{R}\})\right)|\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_j |,
$$
where $|\psi_i\rangle$ denotes the $i$th electronic diabatic state (usually referred to the Franck-Condon point), $T_{ii}$ is the corresponding nuclear kinetic energy operator, and $V_{ij}(\{\mathbf{R}\})$ is the potential energy operator dependent on the nuclear coordinates $\{\mathbf{R}\}$. The functions $V_{ii}(\{\mathbf{R}\})$ are the so-called potential energy surfaces (PES), while $V_{ij}(\{\mathbf{R}\})$, with $i\neq j$, correspond to diabatic vibronic couplings. These PES can be seamlessly formulated as sums of products and are, therefore, suitable fodder for simulations with MCTDH.
As far as I am aware, the only real limitation for ML-MCTDH is that the hierarchical expansion, or ML-MCTDH tree, needs to be carefully crafted; otherwise, the method won't converge. Furthermore, there's no definite systematic approach to generating good trees.
My question is, could it happen that it is impossible to find a working tree for a PES within the vibronic coupling Hamiltonian framework? If that's the case, what characteristics would that PES have? Are there realistic molecular systems featuring such PES?
